# Add a tag in remote repository without adding the repo on local

Tags: git

Do have anyway to add a tag in remote repository without cloning/adding it on local. I just need to do it for marking QA builds

Comment: Can you log in on the remote?  If so, easy: run `git tag` command over there.  If not, hard, might as well just clone.

Comment: Yeah...I knew this..good way anyway..thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a remote tag having no local tags at all with

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/tags/foo
```

You can remove the same tag with

```
git push origin :refs/tags/foo
```

Here's an explanation.

Take the command `git push`. Without being too strict, the general syntax could be interpreted as

```
git push where what:onto
```

`where` is the name of the remote repository you want to push to.

`what` a reference (using one of the several kinds offered by git) to a commit of your local repository. It can be a SHA1, a branch name, a tag name or other.

`onto` in the name you want the remote will use to reference the thing you are pushing.

For example

```
git push origin master:master
```

is pushing to `origin` the commit (and all the other previous commits, if the remote does not have them) pointed by `master`, asking the remote repository to call it `master`, that is to save in its `master` branch the exact same SHA1 recorded in your local  `master` branch (this is not exactly true, but accept this example to understand the principle).

Now, as a matter of facts, branches and tags are just ordinary files storing the `SHA1` of a commit. You could see them as sort pointer variables, with a reference to some commit in the repository.
Branches and tags are stored in `.git/refs/heads` and `.git/refs/tags`

Try with

```
cat .git/refs/heads/master
```

So, the previous could have been written

```
git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

If you want to create a tag `foo` in the remote repository pointing to the same commit that is referenced by your `master` branch, you could run

```
git push origin master:refs/tags/foo
```

If you want to create a tag on the remote repository referencing exactly the same commit you are in at the moment, use the special branch `HEAD`, which is a pointer to your current position

For example, try with

```
git checkout master
cat .git/refs/heads/master
cat .git/HEAD
```

It should give twice the same value, confirming that `master` and `HEAD` reference the same commit, that is, you are *on* `master`

So, in order to create a remote tag referencing your local current commit use

```
git push origin HEAD:/refs/tags/a_tag_name
```

It is somehow like you are asking the remote `origin` to write in its file `refs/tags/a_tag_name` the value of the SHA1 contained in your local `HEAD`. This creates the tag in the remote repository.

If you push a `null` you will delete the tag

```
git push origin :/refs/tags/a_tag_name
```

That's all

Comment: How can you annotate a tag you create this way?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to push a tag to remote that didn't exist in local **and** was at the remote's head, rather than mine.

```
git push origin origin/head:refs/tags/foo
```

We were having the problem of deploying from individual machines, who may or may not have gotten the latest, and tagging the release. The tag would show up further down the log even though the release incorporated the latest commit.

The answer above is correct and very well-explained, but didn't address my variation on the asked question.